# Cannot access port 5432 with VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, port

I have a postgresql server up and running on my VM instance, and I want to connect this to port `5432` to fly data from my VM into my Postgresql database.

However, whenever I try:

```
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel <my-instance> 5432  --local-host-port=localhost:5432 --zone=us-east4-b
```

I get this error:

> (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) While checking if a connection can be made: Error while connecting [4003: 'failed to connect to backend']. (Failed to connect to port 5432)

I have created a fire-wall and added a network tag to my VM instance, and included the ports `5432, 3389` to the firewall with the IP `35.235.240.0/20`, as suggested on [Using IAP for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule).

Additionally, I have created a `principal user` granting access to the IAP-tunnel for the specific ports `5432, 3389`, yet I still get the error as shown above.

Interestingly, even when I configure my firewall I still get a `warning` message when configuring for the IAP

[image]

Secondly - I have created a new project and re-started the entire process and instead of the error above, I just get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Unable to open socket on port [5432]
```

My guess is that this error suggests some progress has happened, and finding out how to open the socket is the next path.

Comment: 1) Port 3389 is used for Windows RDP. 2) Did you configure the VM with a public  IP address? 3) Verify that port 5432 is actually open a being listened on at the public and private IP addresses. 3)  Copy and paste the images into your question. Use text when possible instead of images. I will not click on the links in a question for security reasons.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for the comment. Turns out I need 10 rep for the image to reveal itself :/ ... additionally, I have checked with `telnet localhost 5432` and I can call into that port without an issue on both my public engine (pc) and private (vm). My VM has all the default settings when creating a google cloud VM, s I believe the IP address is public as all IPV4 IP addresses are public.

Comment: You should have enough rep now to fix the image. Testing with **localhost** is pointless. You need to verify the external interfaces. If you have a public IP address, then test with a PostgreSQL client to connect to the public IP address. Why are you using an IAP tunnel? There are limitations to using tunnels for data transfer.